# Dart How to load file in runtime

Tags: dart

I'm writing a discord bot using the nyxx library and want use dynamic file import for load command info and handler. But, after 5 hours of searching with Google, I didn't find anything to help me do that.

In Node.js, I can use `require()` or `import()` for it: Does the dart have something like that?

A small code snippet, showing what I want do:

```js
this.commands = new Collection();
fs.readdirSync('./src/commands').filter(( f ) => f.endsWith( '.js' )).forEach((file) => {
    const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
    this.commands.set( command.info.name, command );
});
```

Is it possible to do this or not? (I don't like to write many imports for commands and register it in lib.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in theory use [`Isolate.spawnUri`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-isolate/Isolate/spawnUri.html) to spawn external Dart programs to run in its own `Isolate` instances that can then communicate back to the main program using `SendPort`.

It does, however, come with some limitations. E.g. it is very limited what types of objects you can send though `SendPort` when using `spawnUri` since the two programs does not share any type information (compared to `Isolate.spawn` which does allow you to send your own custom types). The documented types you can send can be found here:

> - Null
> - bool
> - int
> - double
> - String
> - List or Map (whose elements are any of these)
> - TransferableTypedData
> - SendPort
> - Capability

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html

But it does allow us to make some kind of protocol and you can create some helper class around this to handle the conversion of a known object structure into e.g. `Map<String, Object>`.

A small example that works with Dart VM would be:

Your command implemented as: `command.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';

void main(List<String> arguments, Map<String, Object> message) {
  final userName = message['username'] as String;
  final sendPort = message['port'] as SendPort;

  sendPort.send('Hi $userName. '
      'You got a message from my external command program!');
}
```

Your server that calls your command: `server.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';

void main() {
  final recievePort = ReceivePort();

  recievePort.listen((message) {
    print('Got the following message: $message');
    recievePort.close();
  });

  Isolate.spawnUri(Uri.file('command.dart'), [], {
    'username': 'julemand101',
    'port': recievePort.sendPort,
  });
}
```

If running this with: `dart server.dart` you, hopefully, get:

```
Got the following message: Hi julemand101. You got a message from my external command program!
```

If you want to compile your application, you can do so by doing the following. You need to compile the `command.dart`, since a compiled Dart program does not understand how to read Dart code.

```
dart compile exe server.dart
dart compile aot-snapshot command.dart
```

You should here change `Uri.file('command.dart')` to `Uri.file('command.aot')` since the file-extension for `aot-snapshot` are `.aot`.

If everything works, you should be able to see:

```
> .\server.exe                
Got the following message: Hi julemand101. You got a message from my external command program!
```